# How to add listener to the checkbox inside a listview that uses CheckBoxListCell

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a listview that uses a `CheckBoxListCell` to display a list with checkboxes next to the items. How do I add a listener to this checkbox to know when an item as been selected or unselected?
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Solution**

You don't add a listener to the checkbox.  You add a listener to the observable property of the object which was associated with the checkbox by the [CheckBoxListCell.forListView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxListCell.html#forListView-javafx.util.Callback-) routine.

Setting up the association:

```
ListView<Task> checklist = new ListView<>(tasks);
checklist.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(Task::selectedProperty));
```

Adding a listener for all items:

```
tasks.forEach(task -> task.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
    if (isSelected) {
        // . . .
    } else {
        // . . .
    }
}));
```

**Documentation**

The process is described in the [CheckBoxListCell.forListView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxListCell.html#forListView-javafx.util.Callback-) javadoc like so:

> `getSelectedProperty` - A Callback that, given an object of type T
>   (which is a value taken out of the ListView.items list), will
>   return an ObservableValue that represents whether the given
>   item is selected or not. This ObservableValue will be bound
>   bidirectionally (meaning that the CheckBox in the cell will set/unset
>   this property based on user interactions, and the CheckBox will
>   reflect the state of the ObservableValue, if it changes externally).

**Sample Program**

A sample program which demonstrated some of the patterns which could be used with CheckBoxListCell:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CheckList extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        ObservableList<Task> tasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                Arrays.stream(taskNames).map(Task::new).collect(Collectors.toList())
        );

        ListView<String> reactionLog = new ListView<>();
        tasks.forEach(task -> task.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
            if (isSelected) {
                reactionLog.getItems().add(reactionStrings.get(task.getName()));
                reactionLog.scrollTo(reactionLog.getItems().size() - 1);
            }
        }));

        ListView<Task> checklist = new ListView<>(tasks);
        checklist.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(Task::selectedProperty, new StringConverter<Task>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Task object) {
                return object.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public Task fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }
        }));

        HBox layout = new HBox(10, checklist, reactionLog);
        layout.setPrefSize(350, 150);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Task {
        private ReadOnlyStringWrapper name = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper();
        private BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        public Task(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }
        public ReadOnlyStringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
            return selected;
        }
        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected.get();
        }
        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            this.selected.set(selected);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static final String[] taskNames = {
            "Walk the dog",
            "Skin the cat",
            "Feed the pig"
    };

    private static final Map<String, String> reactionStrings = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        reactionStrings.put("Walk the dog", "The dog thanks you");
        reactionStrings.put("Skin the cat", "The cat hates you");
        reactionStrings.put("Feed the pig", "The pig wants more");
    }
}
```

Sample output after selecting the first item once and the third item three times.

[image: piggy]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative if the item does not already have a property that indicates if it has been selected or not:

```
public class CheckedListViewCheckObserver<T> extends SimpleObjectProperty<Pair<T, Boolean>> {

    BooleanProperty getObserverForObject(T object) {
        BooleanProperty value = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        value.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            CheckedListViewCheckObserver.this.set(new Pair<>(object, newValue));
        });
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then to use it, you simply do:

```
CheckedListViewCheckObserver observer = new CheckedListViewCheckObserver<>();
checklist.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(observer::getObserverForObject));
```

Now you can set a listener to listen for any changes:

```
observer.addListener((obs, old, curr) -> {
    if (curr.getValue()) {
        System.out.println("You have checked " + curr.getKey());
    } else {
        System.out.println("You have unchecked " + curr.getKey());
    }
});
```

The advantage of this method is that it does not depend on the objects being used; Instead, since it is generic, you can simply attach it to an already existing listview and it starts working off the bat.

Hope this helps someone.