# Best practice to decorate an ObservableList and retain change events

Tags: java, design-patterns, javafx

My datasource provides an `ObservableList<String>`, however for my ListView I need an `ObservableList<Warning>`.

A `Warning` is basically just a decorator for the strings, adding a boolean to provide a means for tracking the state of checkboxes my ListView, as proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25347833/4014509) answer.

```
class Warning {

    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper name;
    private final BooleanProperty checked;

    /* ... */

}
```

Currently I am observing change-events in the original list and add/remove items in the warnings list manually:

```
ObservableList<String> stringList = ...;
ObservableList<Warning> warningList = ...;

stringList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> change) {
        if (change.wasAdded()) {
            warningList.addAll(change.getAddedSubList().stream().map(Warning::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
            change.getRemoved().forEach(str -> {
                warningList.removeIf(w -> str.equals(w.name));
            });
        }
    }

});
```

**My question is:** Is there a more elegant way to decorate my String-typed list, so it can be used as a Warning-typed list without manually passing through change events?

To be more precise: If a string is added to or removed from the original list, I want to see this change immediately in the Warnings-list and thus the ListView.

Comment: The [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind/tree/master/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/easybind) framework has some functionality for this, basically you can call `ObservableList<Warning> warningList = EasyBind.map(stringList, Warning::new);`. The implementation there uses a subclass of `TransformationList`, so I think it basically boils down to the same thing you are doing.

Comment: @James_D thank you. I don't want to include a whole framework just for this one problem, but the `TransformationList` is still a good hint

Comment: Yes, makes sense (though the framework is very lightweight). The [source code](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/easybind/MappedList.java) is available so you can see how it's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been thinking about this a bit since you posted it. Using EasyBind as I had suggested in the comment won't work, since it would create a new `Warning` every time you called `get(...)` on the mapped list. So

```
stringList.add("foo");
warningList.get(0).setChecked(true);
assert warningList.get(0).isChecked();
```

would fail.

Additionally, your mechanism goes wrong (I think) if you have duplicate entries in the source list (`stringList`), as you would remove all corresponding entries from the `warningList` when a single element was removed from the `stringList`. In fact, getting the removed elements correct is quite tricky.

Here is a solution based on Tomas Mikula's [`MappedList`](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/easybind/MappedList.java) which caches the mapping between the source elements and the mapped elements. It uses an `IdentityHashMap` to ensure that duplicate elements behave correctly in both lists. Note this only works for the specific case where you want to create new objects when items are added to the source list, so it is not intended (and would not work) as a replacement for the mechanism in EasyBind.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.IdentityHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WrappedObjectListExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<String> stringList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three");
        ObservableList<Warning> warningList = new CachingMappedList<Warning, String>(stringList, Warning::new);

        ListView<String> stringListView = new ListView<>(stringList);
        ListView<Warning> warningListView = new ListView<>(warningList);

        warningListView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(Warning::checkedProperty));

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (! textField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                stringList.add(textField.getText());
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });

        Button remove = new Button("Remove");
        remove.setOnAction(e -> stringList.remove(stringListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()));
        remove.disableProperty().bind(stringListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());

        HBox lists = new HBox(10, stringListView, warningListView);
        VBox root = new VBox(10, lists, textField, remove);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Warning {
        private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper name = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper();
        private final BooleanProperty checked = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        public Warning(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public final ReadOnlyStringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final BooleanProperty checkedProperty() {
            return this.checked;
        }

        public final boolean isChecked() {
            return this.checkedProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setChecked(final boolean checked) {
            this.checkedProperty().set(checked);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }

    }

    public static class CachingMappedList<S,T> extends TransformationList<S, T> {

        private final Function<T, S> mapper ;

        private final IdentityHashMap<T, S> cache ;

        public CachingMappedList(ObservableList<T> source, Function<T,S> mapper) {
            super(source);
            this.mapper = mapper ;
            this.cache = new IdentityHashMap<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected void sourceChanged(Change<? extends T> c) {

            fireChange(new Change<S>(this) {

                @Override
                public boolean wasAdded() {
                    return c.wasAdded();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean wasRemoved() {
                    return c.wasRemoved();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean wasReplaced() {
                    return c.wasReplaced();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean wasUpdated() {
                    return c.wasUpdated();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean wasPermutated() {
                    return c.wasPermutated();
                }


                @Override
                public boolean next() {
                    return c.next();
                }

                @Override
                public void reset() {
                    c.reset();
                }

                @Override
                public int getFrom() {
                    return c.getFrom();
                }

                @Override
                public int getTo() {
                    return c.getTo();
                }

                @Override
                public List<S> getRemoved() {
                    List<S> removed = new ArrayList<>();
                    c.getRemoved().forEach(t -> removed.add(cache.get(t)));
                    return removed;
                }

                @Override
                public int getPermutation(int i) {
                    return c.getPermutation(i);
                }

                @Override
                protected int[] getPermutation() {
                    throw new AssertionError("Unreachable code");
                }

            });

            // clean up cache:

            c.reset();
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    c.getRemoved().forEach(cache::remove);
                }
            }            
        }

        @Override
        public int getSourceIndex(int index) {
            return index ;
        }

        @Override
        public S get(int index) {
            return cache.computeIfAbsent(getSource().get(index), mapper);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return getSource().size();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you for investing your time into this solution! I think **the cache is the important part**, as I don't want on-the-fly mapping for every access to any item in the list, but rather create/delete warnings on changes only. I don't have duplicates. But since I didn't specify this in my question it's good, that you pointed this out.

Comment: Subclassing `TransformationList` just seems right too, even though it's more verbose. It has the advantage of being unmodifiable, so you enforce the relationship (instead of just relying on the programmer not directly modifying the target list). There was an identical question posted today, so it seemed worth the effort (and I wanted to correct my error in saying you could use `EasyBind.map(...)` as a solution, which is plain wrong).