# JavaFX ObservableList content binding

Tags: java, list, binding, javafx, observablelist

I know that you can create a list binding like so:

```
ObservableList list1 = ...;
ObservableList list2 = ...;

Bindings.createContentBinding(list1, list2);
```

But I want to bind them in a special way. Say I have these types:

```
Object obj = ...;
MyObject myObj = new MyObject(obj);
```

And these lists:

```
ObservableList<Object> objList = ...;
ObservableList<MyObject> myObjList = ...;
```

Every time a new object in `objList` is added, I want one to be added into `myObjList` with `new MyObject(obj);`

You can bind other properties with `Bindings.create*Binding(...)`, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for lists.

Any ideas on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: There is no build in capability for this. Look at [TransformationList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/TransformationList.html) which could be helpful for getting a starting point.

Comment: This is actually quite tricky to get right. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230312/best-practice-to-decorate-an-observablelist-and-retain-change-events/31277978#31277978 (this is more or less an exact duplicate of that question).

Answer (score 0):

```
objList.addListener(e->{
    if(e.wasAdded)
    {
        if(myObjectList.size>=e.getFrom())
            myObjList.Add(new myObject(objList.get(objList.size-1)));
        else{
             myObjList.Add(e.getFrom(),new myObject(objList.get(e.getFrom()));
     }
    }
    if(e.wasRemoved)
    {
         myObjectList.Remove(e.getFrom());
    }   
    if(e.wasPermutated)
    {
         //handle this as well
    }
});
```

Hope that helps :)

Edited to get the changed object instead of assuming the last one was added. Also removing objects. There is probably some off-by-ones in there as I have not compiled it and checked it. Feel free to edit it if it is. Hopefully it is at least good enough to get a general idea of how it could be implemented.

Comment: And what happens if it is added with an Index to the objList! You will add the last element to the myObjList twice.

Comment: Or if you remove an element...?

Comment: Or anything else will happen, like permutation :-)

Comment: e.wasAdded prevents other changeevents such as remove to be triggered. (have I misunderstood you James_D?)

NwDx was however correct so I have changed my answer to account for that.

Comment: Yes, you have misunderstood (both myself and NwDx): if you remove an element from the source list, you need to ensure the corresponding element is also removed from the target list. Additionally, @NwDx was pointing out that if you do `objList.add(someIndex, someObject)`, you really need to make sure you add not only the correct element, but you add it in the correct place in the target list (you fixed one part, but not the other). And your new code won't compile: `getFrom()` returns an `int`... This question is a duplicate anyway: the linked question has a correct version of your solution.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry,  I fully blame my tiredness. Hopefully this will be good enough...

Comment: I recommend you actually write some code to test this out, and test out all the possible ways of modifying the underlying list. You seem to be assuming (among other things) that only one element can be added or removed during any single change event... As I said in the comment below the question, it is quite tricky to get this right.

Comment: Why don't you iterate over the changes with `e.getAddedList()`?