# JavaFX property adapter for TableView

Tags: java, javafx, pojo

For DTO I use POJO. So to make bidirectional binding I create adapter. I mean, something like that:

POJO:

```
public class Temp{
   private BigDecimal weight;
   private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;
   public Temp() {
        this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
   }
   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }
   public BigDecimal getWeight() {
     return weight;
   }
   public void setWeight(BigDecimal weight) {
     BigDecimal pv = this.weight;
    this.weight = weight;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("weight", pv, weight);
   }
}
```

I have the following adapter:

```
public class TempAdapter {
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> weightProperty;
    public TempAdapter(Temp temp) {
        try {
            weightProperty=new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder<BigDecimal>().bean(temp).name("weight").build();
            weightProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<BigDecimal>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends BigDecimal> ov, BigDecimal t, BigDecimal t1) {
                  ....
                }
            });
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
 public ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> getWeightProperty() {
    return weightProperty;
}
```

However, I can't understand how to use this adapter with TableView. The reason I want to use adapter for TableView is that otherwise we will have to duplicate the code of the adapter in TableView if we  using POJO for DTO with TableView.

As I understand for every row in TableView we must create a new Instance of Adapter and I can't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution without an adapter class**

First note you don't necessarily need an adapter class; you can just create the `JavaBeanProperty` instances where you need them: in this case in the cell value factory for the table. If there is just one (or perhaps two) places in the UI where you need to bind directly to a JavaFX Property corresponding to properties in your POJO, then this is probably the way to go.

Here's a complete example of this technique, using the usual Oracle `Person` table example. In this example, there is no adapter class: the table just creates the `JavaBeanStringProperty` adapters in the cell value factory. There is an edit form, which just interacts with the POJO class directly.

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.adapter.JavaBeanStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.adapter.JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class PojoTable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn = createColumn("First Name", "firstName");
        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn = createColumn("Last Name", "lastName");

        table.getColumns().add(firstNameColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(lastNameColumn);


        Button button = new Button("Show data");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            table.getItems().stream().map(person -> person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
            System.out.println();
        });

        Button edit = new Button("Edit");
        edit.disableProperty().bind(table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
        edit.setOnAction(e -> edit(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), primaryStage));

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown")
        );

        HBox buttons = new HBox(10, button, edit);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, buttons, null);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(buttons, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(buttons, new Insets(10));
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void edit(Person person, Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane editPane = new GridPane();
        TextField firstNameField = new TextField(person.getFirstName());
        TextField lastNameField = new TextField(person.getLastName());
        Button okButton = new Button("OK");
        Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
        HBox buttons = new HBox(10, okButton, cancelButton);

        editPane.addRow(0, new Label("First Name:"), firstNameField);
        editPane.addRow(1, new Label("Last Name:"), lastNameField);
        editPane.add(buttons, 0, 2, 2, 1);

        GridPane.setHalignment(buttons, HPos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setMargin(buttons, new Insets(10));

        editPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(editPane);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        cancelButton.setOnAction(e -> stage.hide());
        okButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            person.setFirstName(firstNameField.getText());
            person.setLastName(lastNameField.getText());
            stage.hide();
        });

        stage.show();
    }

    private TableColumn<Person, String> createColumn(String title, String property) {
        TableColumn<Person, String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            Person p = cellData.getValue();
            try {
                JavaBeanStringProperty prop = new JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder()
                    .bean(p)
                    .name(property)
                    .build();
                return prop;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Person {
        private String firstName ;
        private String lastName ;

        private PropertyChangeSupport support ;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName ;
            this.lastName = lastName ;

            support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            String previous = this.firstName ;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            support.firePropertyChange("firstName", previous, firstName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            String previous = this.lastName ;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            support.firePropertyChange("lastName", previous, lastName);
        }

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            support.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }

        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            support.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Solution using an adapter class**

Note that in the above example, the text fields in the editor can't use bindings directly with the POJO class (because it doesn't expose any JavaFX properties); if you wanted to do so you could create more `JavaBeanStringProperty`s for the purpose, but that would end up duplicating code. If you wanted to be able to do this, then it might become beneficial to use an adapter class. Here is what the code might look like using this solution. Note that now the adapter class exposes JavaFX properties, so the table's cell value factory can just map directly to those properties: the creation of the `JavaBeanStringProperty`s is encapsulated in one place (the adapter class):

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.adapter.JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class PojoTable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<PersonAdapter> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<PersonAdapter, String> firstNameColumn = createColumn("First Name", PersonAdapter::firstNameProperty);
        TableColumn<PersonAdapter, String> lastNameColumn = createColumn("Last Name", PersonAdapter::lastNameProperty);

        table.getColumns().add(firstNameColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(lastNameColumn);

        List<Person> data = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown")
        );


        Button button = new Button("Show data");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            data.stream().map(person -> person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
            System.out.println();
        });

        Button edit = new Button("Edit");
        edit.disableProperty().bind(table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
        edit.setOnAction(e -> edit(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), primaryStage));

        data.stream().map(PersonAdapter::new).forEach(table.getItems()::add);

        HBox buttons = new HBox(10, button, edit);
        buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, buttons, null);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(buttons, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(buttons, new Insets(10));
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void edit(PersonAdapter person, Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane editPane = new GridPane();
        TextField firstNameField = new TextField();
        firstNameField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(person.firstNameProperty());

        TextField lastNameField = new TextField();
        lastNameField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(person.lastNameProperty());

        Button okButton = new Button("OK");
        HBox buttons = new HBox(10, okButton);

        editPane.addRow(0, new Label("First Name:"), firstNameField);
        editPane.addRow(1, new Label("Last Name:"), lastNameField);
        editPane.add(buttons, 0, 2, 2, 1);

        GridPane.setHalignment(buttons, HPos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setMargin(buttons, new Insets(10));

        editPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(editPane);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        okButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            stage.hide();
        });

        stage.show();
    }

    private TableColumn<PersonAdapter, String> createColumn(String title, Function<PersonAdapter, StringProperty> property) {
        TableColumn<PersonAdapter, String> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Person {
        private String firstName ;
        private String lastName ;

        private PropertyChangeSupport support ;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName ;
            this.lastName = lastName ;

            support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            String previous = this.firstName ;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            support.firePropertyChange("firstName", previous, firstName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            String previous = this.lastName ;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            support.firePropertyChange("lastName", previous, lastName);
        }

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            support.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }

        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            support.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public static class PersonAdapter {
        private final Person person ;

        private final StringProperty firstName ;
        private final StringProperty lastName ;

        public PersonAdapter(Person person) {
            this.person = person ;

            try {
                this.firstName = new JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder()
                    .bean(person)
                    .name("firstName")
                    .build();

                this.lastName = new JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder()
                    .bean(person)
                    .name("lastName")
                    .build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }

        public Person getPerson() { 
            return person ;
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The one possible disadvantage to this approach is that changes to the underlying list (`data` in the simple example) will not propagate to the table (this means adding or removing elements from `data` will not change the table; calling `setFirstName` or `setLastName` on the existing elements of the table will allow for updates). For techniques to manage this, see [Best practice to decorate an ObservableList and retain change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230312/best-practice-to-decorate-an-observablelist-and-retain-change-events/31277978#31277978)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This is what I meant in my question. We create ObjectProperty both in adapter and in ValueFactory -> code duplication. So can we use the same adapter in TableView.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you need your adapter class. The `JavaBeanPropertyAdapter` already does the "adapting" between the JavaBean property and the JavaFX Observable value; you don't need another level of adapters. Can you not omit that class entirely, as in my answer (there is no code duplication in my answer, right?).

Comment: I mean, yes, you can use the adapter class in the `TableView`, but you would have to create a `TableView<TempAdapter>` instead of a `TableView<Temp>` and populate it. And, assuming you are generating a `List<Temp>` somewhere, you would have to create a `List<TempAdapter>` and ensure it was always in sync with the original `List<Temp>`. The whole point of the `JavaBeanPropertyAdapter` classes is to let you use plain old JavaBeans in your controls...

Comment: Thanks. I will try to explain the core of my answer. I have POJO as DTO. And I have simple CRUD application. There is table with items and selecting one item in table you can open this item in form for CRUD. In this form there are different TextFields, TextAreas etc. So in this form we use adapter. So in sum we have table and a form. In form we use adapter. In table we (using the approach you suggest) we DUPLICATE the adapter. So this is the situation I don't like.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you need the adapter class at all. Just use your POJO as the type for the table, with the approach I suggest (which is not duplicating anything, because the adapter class doesn't exist). Have your form edit the POJO directly. Get rid of the adapter class.

Comment: Ok. I will try explain step by step. There is table and a form. In both we have to create bindings for using POJO. Let's call this as `binding code` - `JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder. create(). bean(person)                       .name("firstName"). build();` Can we put this binding code in one place and use it both in form and in table?

Comment: OK, I get the need for the adapter now. So why not just use the adapter as the table type, and map the cell value factory directly to the weight property? I.e. `weightColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getWeightProperty());`? (Though I recommend you rename `getWeightProperty()` as `weightProperty()` so it matches the [JavaFX property pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107)

Comment: 1)So do you think that the best way to solve this problem for table is to use TableView<TempAdapter>? 2)Thank you for advice I will rename to weightProperty.

Comment: I still think it's possible to manage without the adapter class: see updated example. Whether or not this is more convenient for you depends on your exact scenario. If you use the adapter class though, then you just use the property you expose in that class directly as the result of the cell value factory, instead of duplicating code. If I have time I'll add a second example using an adapter class.